# GitLab push not possible and always results in asking for git-user password

Tags: debian, git, ssh-keys, debian-lenny, gitlab

I have a problem with GitLab. Everything is fine, but I can't push. It is asking me all the time the password of the user git.

Is it a problem, that I first installed the Omnibus package and then uninstalled it, because I use Apache and this package uses Nginx?

I installed GitLab with [this tutorial](http://blog.florentlim.com/how-to-install-gitlab-on-debian-7-wheezy-on-apache2-http-server/). It worked, but the other users couldn't create projects.

Then I tried uninstalling it, reinstalling and updating it. Now everybody can create projects, but when somebody is trying to push, it asks for a git password.

SSH keys are created and saved in GitLab. The folder `/home/git/.ssh` doesn't exist. I found it here: `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh`. Is that a sign that git isn't configured correctly?

Comment: What do you mean `The folder /home/git/.ssh is not exciting. I found it here: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh. Is that a sign that git isn't configured correctly?` Users need to use their own keys. So user A creates his own keys and B as well, which means that if B@user pushes to gitlab a password prompt for user B occurs and A if user A is trying to push.

Comment: Please update the question if this issue is applicable to all users or just one.

Comment: `Everything is fine, but I can't push`. So every user can `pull`?

Answer (score 1):

With Gitlab, You can clone via HTTP or via SSH. Which URL do you use ?

- via HTTP(S), you must provide the login/password from your GitLab UI account.
- via SSH, you must configure correctly SSH on your client : first try to keep your private key (corresponding to the public key configured in your GitLab account) at the default place where SSH will search for it : `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Otherwise, you must provide additional configuration in the `~/.ssh/config` file.

All this information concern the developer configuration, not the server.